# How to make sure the MVC generated control within div?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Hi i got the below partial view which will display control inside div, but the control always created longer than the div, is there any better way to control in css instead of hardcode the width of each control?

```
<fieldset  class="fieldsetthinner">
    <div style="float: left; width: 10%"><p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.decBeginQty)<p></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 10%"><p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.decEndQty )<p></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 10%"><p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.decBeginAmt )<p></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 10%"><p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.decEndAmt )<p></div>

    <div style="float: left; width: 20%"><p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.tintFactorType)<p></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 10%"><p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.decMaxBonus )<p></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 10%"><p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.nvarMsg )<p></div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 10%"><p>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.varVCode  )<p></div>
</fieldset>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are not closing your `<p>` tags correctly

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<fieldset  class="fieldsetthinner">
 <div class="editor"><p>THIS IS AN EDITOR<p></div>
 <div class="editor"><p>THIS IS AN EDITOR<p></div>
 <div class="editor"><p>THIS IS AN EDITOR<p></div>
 <div class="editor"><p>THIS IS AN EDITOR<p></div>
 <div class="editor2"><p>THIS IS AN EDITOR<p></div>
 <div class="editor"><p>THIS IS AN EDITOR<p></div>
 <div class="editor"><p>THIS IS AN EDITOR<p></div>
 <div class="editor"><p>THIS IS AN EDITOR<p></div>
</fieldset>
```

CSS

```
fieldset.fieldsetthinner
{
    background-color:gray;
}

.editor
{
  float:left;
  width:10%;
  background-color:red;
}
.editor2
{
 background-color:blue;
 float:left;
 width:20%;
}
```

Just add this in your CSS. I added background color to show you the difference. You could use class or id so that you won't repeat typing similar style like what you are doing.

Here is the working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y77g/22/)